# php, sort an array from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting

I'm running a query on three columns; one column contains text, the other two contain numbers. I do a calculation on these numbers to get a new number called $average. I then spit out the result to an html table. The rows in the table are sorted in the order they come out of the database. I'm trying to sort the table so that the data is displayed from highest $average to lowest (while still be correctly associated with the correct text value from the first column).

I've tried some `asort` and `foreach` stuff, but I've only succeeded in making a mess of errors.

Any ideas as how I go about this? 
Thanks.

This is the current state of play:

```
/ db query
  if (!$result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT quiz_name, 
                                            quiz_attempts, 
                                            cumulative_score 
                                       FROM scoredata")) {
  echo("There was a problem: " . mysqli_error($link));
  exit();
  }
...
// got results?
  if(mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1) {

  $output = "";
  $output .= "<table>\n";
  $output .= "<tr><th>Quiz name</th> <th>Played</th> <th>Avg. score</th></tr>\n";

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $output .= "<tr><td>".str_replace('_', ' ', $row['quiz_name']) . "</td>";
    $output .= "<td>" . $row['quiz_attempts'] . "</td>";

    // calculate average score
    $average = $row['cumulative_score']/$row['quiz_attempts'];

    $output .= "<td>" . round($average,2) . "</td></tr>";
   }

  $output .= "</table>\n";
  echo $output;
}
...
```

Comment: You can sort your data in your DB - no need to sort it after receiving.

Comment: and do the calculation with your query.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't sort in your SQL query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do calculation and sorting in your query:

```
SELECT 
    quiz_name, 
    quiz_attempts, 
    cumulative_score,
    (cumulative_score/quiz_attempts) as score_avg
FROM scoredata
ORDER BY score_avg DESC
```

Comment: Ah, I had no idea things could be done this way. Works just fine, and is a lot neater. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can

- let the db do the sorting (as suggested by other posters)
- sort the data yourself (as you are trying to do)
- let the user sort the data via JavaScript functions. My favourite is
  http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/lib/table/

Answer (score 0):

Make this your query

```
    SELECT quiz_name, 
           quiz_attempts, 
           cumulative_score,
           cumulative_score / quiz_attempts as avg_score
    FROM scoredata
    ORDER BY avg_score
```